Norm of integral less than or equal to integral of norm of function; Le Gall
Let $(E,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space equipped with a measure $\mu$. If $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is integrable, then we have $\left|\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right|\leq\int |f|\,\mathrm{d}\mu$. If $f$ is complex-valued and integrable, Le Gall in his book Measure Theory, Probability and Stochastic Processes argues that (on page 29, bottom) the easiest way to obtain the inequality is by noticing $$\left|\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu\right|=\sup_{a\in\mathbb C,|a|=1}a\cdot \int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\sup_{a\in\mathbb C,|a|=1}\int a\cdot f\,\mathrm{d}\mu,\tag1$$where $a\cdot z$ denotes the Euclidean scalar product on $\mathbb C$ identified with $\mathbb R^2$. I wonder

What is the author using in the first equality? Why does the second equality hold?
How does one obtain the inequality from $(1)$?


This question doesn't make sense. What is $f$?

$f:E\to\mathbb C$ is measurable and integrable.

The first equality holds because generally for $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$|v| = \sup_{\substack{u \in \mathbb{R}^2 \\ |u| = 1}} \left< u, v \right>,$$
where $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ denotes the Euclidean dot product on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The identity is true because for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $|u| = 1$ we have $\left< u, v \right> \leqslant |v|$ by Cauchy-Schwarz, and $u = \frac{v}{|v|}$ gives equality.
The second equality holds because generally for $u \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and integrable $f : E \to \mathbb{R}^2$
$$\left< u, \int \limits_E f \, \text{d} \mu \right> = \int \limits_E \left< u, f \right> \, \text{d} \mu.$$
This follows directly from the linearity of integral.
To get the desired inequality simply notice that $\left< u, f \right> \leqslant |u| \cdot |f| \leqslant |f|$ when $|u| = 1$, and so
$$\sup_{|u| = 1} \int \limits_E \left< u, f \right> \, \text{d} \mu \leqslant \int \limits_E |f| \,  \text{d} \mu.$$
